# ES6 import multiple files

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, gulp, bower

I'm migrating from gulp (using bower) to webpack. Within bower.json I had used this setup to include Waypoints.

```
"waypoints": {
  "main": [
    "lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/infinite.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/inview.min.js"
  ],
```

What's the best way to do this with webpack using ES6 imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. 
You can use the entry in your Webpack config to specify multiple files to import.
For eg,

```
entry: {
  main: [  
    "lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/infinite.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/inview.min.js"
  ],
},
```

Also, its good practice to split the vendor chunks like this:

```
entry: {
  app: ['./index.js'],
  vendor: [  
    "lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/infinite.min.js",
    "lib/shortcuts/inview.min.js"
  ],
},
```

Comment: Is this method preferred over ES6 imports in my entry JS file?

Comment: Depends. If you want the exported methods from those files, you will have to import them into the source code anyway. That said, its good practice to split the vendor chunks into one bundle with a slightly different config to make the build faster. It can also help in cacheing assets.

Comment: This is perfect and makes a lot of sense. That's a much appreciated answer!

Comment: Do you know how I can keep the order I set under 'vendor' when it compiles?